# Regular pentagon in a square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics

Recently I stumbled upon the following problem:

> What is the area of set of points of unit square that can be covered with a regular pentagon that is contained entirely in the square and whose diagonal has length $1$?

In other words, fix a unit square $S$ and let 
$$\mathcal P = \{P \subset S \mid P \mathrm{\ is \ a \ regular \ pentagon \ with \ diagonal \ of \ length \ } 1 \}.$$
What is the area of $\bigcup \mathcal P$?

Comment: JUst want to know how many elements are there in $\mathcal P$?

Comment: $\mathcal P$ contains continuum elements

Comment: Do you mean:- Inside the unit square, draw as many regular pentagons (with unit diagonals) as possible and sum their areas up?

Comment: No, I mean: calculate the area of the figure obtained by taking the sum of these pentagons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\mathcal U$ be the union of all regular pentagons of diagonal 1 lying wholly in the unit square. We refer to the diagram below.

[image: Pentagons in a square, with contact points highlighted]

Consider a pentagon flush with the square's left side. It rotates while keeping point contact with the bottom and left sides at A and B respectively until it is flush with the bottom side. The locus of R during this rotation then forms part of the boundary of $\mathcal U$; four of these loci (one at each corner) and four straight lines of the pentagon's side length $\Phi=\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}$ form the entire boundary of $\mathcal U$. The regions of the unit square not in $\mathcal U$ are shaded.

Despite initial appearances, the locus of R is not a straight line; we must derive and integrate an expression for it. We know that BA = 1 and BR = RA = $\Phi$. If O is the origin, OX = $x$ and OY = $y$ then a simple application of the Pythagorean theorem yields
$$\left(x+\sqrt{\Phi^2-y^2}\right)^2+\left(y+\sqrt{\Phi^2-x^2}\right)^2=1$$
$$\left(x+\sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt5}2-y^2}\right)^2+\left(y+\sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt5}2-x^2}\right)^2=1$$
From here on we will be relying on Wolfram Alpha for our expressions. Solving for *y* in terms of *x* yields
$$y=\frac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt2}8\sqrt{-2x^2-\sqrt5+3}
-\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}4 x$$
The indefinite integral of this (up to a constant) is
$$\frac{
2\sqrt2(\sqrt5-2)\sin^{-1}\left(x\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt5}2}\right)
-x(2x\sqrt{5+\sqrt5}-(\sqrt5-1)\sqrt{3-\sqrt5-2x^2}) 
}{8\sqrt2}$$
This expression vanishes when $x=0$, so the area of one of the triangular regions not in $\mathcal U$ is its value when $x=\frac{3-\sqrt5}4$, the *x*-coordinate of the bottom-left vertex of the pentagon flush with the square's bottom side. After substituting and a *drastic simplification* we get the very nice
$$\frac{\sqrt5-2}{40}\pi$$
The area of $\mathcal U$ and **the answer to the original question** is therefore
$$1-4\left(\frac{\sqrt5-2}{40}\pi\right)=1-\frac{\sqrt5-2}{10}\pi=0.925837\dots$$
This constant is indexed as [A275967](https://oeis.org/A275967) in Sloane's OEIS.